# program exits automatically

Tags: c++, visual-studio, runtime-error

I have created a simple .exe file. When I run it, it closes automatically instead of saying "press any key to exit".

This is my program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  string answer, yes = "yes";  
  cout << "Is Lucy a top lass ? enter yes or no" << endl;
  cin >> answer;
  if (answer == yes)
  {
    cout << "Correctomundo" << endl;
  }
  else
  {
    cout << " Blasphemy ! " << endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

How do I make it ask the user to press any key before exiting?

Also is there any way I can change it so it says something else instead of "press any key to exit"?

Comment: add a `getch()` at the end before return

Comment: That's normal behavior for a console application.  I would recommend against behaving like a non-standard program.  If you want a persistent console window, open a Command Prompt window first and run your program through that.

Comment: When I do this i get the following :- 
Error C3861 'getch': identifier not found. Can you explain why this is ?

Comment: @jamesdlin . Okay I see, do you know how I change the program so it does not self-exit, without using command prompt ?

Comment: `getch()` is not a standard function.  Don't use that.

Comment: start it without debugging mode.

Comment: Your program is supposed to exit when it's done with its work.  That's how console programs normally behave.  If you violate this rule, then if someone runs your program through a Command Prompt window, they'll have to enter some extra input when your program is done.  That's very weird, and it will make it hard to use your program with redirected input and output.  Don't do that.

Comment: My issue is the person reading does not even get a chance to read the output answer before the program exits, so I need it to stay active until the user has read the word. I  want it to say "press any key to exit" like it does when running it in visual studio. Do you know how I can make this happen ?

Comment: You can: A. Not write a console-mode application and create a windowed application instead. B. Have users run your program through a `.cmd` script that executes your program and runs `pause` afterward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting `system("pause");`
before the `return 0;`

Answer (score 1):

Add `std::getchar();` at the end of your code right before `return 0;`. This will make the program wait for you to type in a character from standard input (the keyboard) and press enter (or just press enter) before it exits. (You might need to `#include <cstdio>` at the beginning for it to work though)

If you want to get really hacky, you can put a breakpoint (you can learn how to do that [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/k80ex6de%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)) at the end of your code but that will only work when you are in debugger mode, not in release mode...

Comment: Note that this will require entering a character *and* pressing Enter (or just pressing Enter).

Comment: I have added this however unfortunately it still exits on its own without any user input. Do you know why this is ?

Comment: @FlewittConnor are you spamming the keyboard when you run the program?